# category description not showing in my woocommerce

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, css

I want to show the category description on my categories pages but I can't access the category.php file and I am using too many plugins already, I don't want to use one more plugin for this. Please give me the solution.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please check if the theme is having archive.php file? If not, then you can use it from any other theme and modify code accordingly.

Comment: @ZealousWeb I can't access the file manager rigth now. Is there any other option?

Comment: You can check the file in admin->appearance->theme editor. Also, you can add file manager plugin to access the files. However, recommend to deactivate plugin after use.